# Expanding memory in a dynamically allocated pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, expand

I am trying to make my array expand when I add an object. But it will not work. I have been searching and searching but can not find the problem... It do not think it will be a hard task for a trained eye, so I thought I could ask you guys. I have two classes, where the class `Timber` is linked to `TimberRegister`, but `Timber` can not see `TimberRegister` while `TimberRegister` can see it. I think it should be enough to show you the cppfile of the `TimberRegister` and the main file, because I am pretty sure the other files are okey and should not affect the error, which seems to be that `toString` cant write the third object because there are no memory for it.

```
#include "timberRegister.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    TimberRegister oak("Oak");
    oak.addTimber("20x10", 4, 10.50);
    oak.addTimber("28x14", 4, 15.00);
    oak.addTimber("15x5", 2, 5);

    int nrOf = oak.getNrOfTimber();
    string* str = new string[nrOf];
    oak.getTimberAsString(str, nrOf);
    cout << oak.getTitle() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; i++) {
    cout << str[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
#include "timberRegister.h"

void TimberRegister::expand() {
    this->capacity += 10;
    Timber* *tmp = new Timber*[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->nrOfTimber; i++) {
        tmp[i] = this->timber[i];
    }
    delete[] this->timber;
    this->timber = tmp;
    this->initiate(this->nrOfTimber);
 }

 void TimberRegister::initiate(int from) {
     for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; i++) {
        this->timber[i] = nullptr;
     }
 }

 void TimberRegister::freeMemory() {
 for (int i = 0; i < this->nrOfTimber; i++) {
        delete this->timber[i];
 }
    delete[] this->timber;
 }

 int TimberRegister::find(string dimension, int meters, double price) {
    int place = -1;
    Timber tmp(dimension, meters, price);

for (int i = 0; i < this->nrOfTimber && place == -1; i++) {
    if (*this->timber[i] == tmp) {
        place = i;
    }
}
return place;
}

TimberRegister::TimberRegister(string title) {
this->title = title;
this->nrOfTimber = 0;
this->capacity = 2;
this->timber = new Timber*[this->capacity];
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    this->timber[i] = nullptr;
}
this->initiate(this->nrOfTimber);
}

TimberRegister::TimberRegister(const TimberRegister &origObj) {
if (this != &origObj) {
    this->title = origObj.title;
    this->nrOfTimber = origObj.capacity;
    this->timber = new Timber*[origObj.capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < origObj.nrOfTimber; i++) {
        this->timber[i] = new Timber(*origObj.timber[i]);
    }
    this->initiate(origObj.getNrOfTimber());
}
}

TimberRegister::~TimberRegister() {
this->freeMemory();
}

TimberRegister TimberRegister::operator=(const TimberRegister & origObj) {
this->freeMemory();

this->title = origObj.title;
this->nrOfTimber = origObj.nrOfTimber;
this->capacity = origObj.capacity;
this->timber = new Timber*[origObj.capacity];
for (int i = 0; i < origObj.capacity; i++) {
    this->timber[i] = new Timber(*origObj.timber[i]);
}
this->initiate(origObj.getNrOfTimber());

return *this;
}

bool TimberRegister::addTimber(string dimension, int meters, double price) {
bool added = false;

if (this->existTimber(dimension, meters, price) == false) {
    if (this->nrOfTimber >= this->capacity) {
        this->expand();
    }
    this->timber[nrOfTimber++] = new Timber(dimension, meters, price);
    added = true;
}
return added;
}

bool TimberRegister::removeTimber(string dimension, int meters, double    price) {
bool removed = false;
int tmp = -1;
tmp = this->find(dimension, meters, price);

if (tmp != -1) {
    delete this->timber[tmp];
    this->timber[tmp] = this->timber[--this->nrOfTimber];
    removed = true;
}
return removed;
}

bool TimberRegister::existTimber(string dimension, int meters, double price) {
bool found = false;
Timber tmp(dimension, meters, price);

for (int i = 0; i < nrOfTimber && found == false; i++) {
    if (*this->timber[i] == tmp) {
        found = true;
    }
}
return found;
}

int TimberRegister::getNrOfTimber() const {
return this->nrOfTimber;
}

string TimberRegister::getTitle() const{
return this->title;
}

void TimberRegister::setTitle(string title) {
this->title = title;
}

void TimberRegister::clear() {
freeMemory();
this->timber = new Timber*[capacity];
}

void TimberRegister::getTimberAsString(string arr[], int nrOf) const {
for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; i++) {
    arr[i] = this->timber[i]->toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: Thank you :) But I can not use it. I need to learn to do this without the vector for now.

Comment: @Henke Then create your own simple vector class (read encapsulation) and use it instead of doing one-off coding like this.  You have `new` strewn all over your code, and it will be a nightmare to make sure `delete` is issued for all of those calls.

Comment: @Henke I see you were taught assignment operator and copy constructor.  Use it to your advantage.  Create your own vector class that manages the memory -- you were taught the tools to do this already.  Once you do that, then replace all of that code where you're doing the `new[]` and `delete[]` calls, and just use your vector class.

Comment: @Henke Why is your copy constructor checking for `this` begin equal to the current object, when the current object is brand new?  Also, why is your assignment operator not checking for self-assignment?  It has serious flaws, and can be demonstrated to be buggy by writing a 2 or 3 line `main` program.  `TimberRegister oak("Oak");    oak.addTimber("20x10", 4, 10.50); oak = oak;`

Comment: Yeah, I will take a look into vectors for my next bigger project. It sounds like a good idea. Also, I am fairly new to C++ and have earlier only been working with classic C. But I am glad that you are noticing me about the problems so I can  look them up and fix them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it will not work. I have been searching and searching but can not find the problem.

One problem I noticed:

```
void TimberRegister::initiate(int from) {
     for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; i++) {
        this->timber[i] = nullptr;
     }
 }
```

In that function, you are making all the pointers `nullptr`. You need to use:

```
void TimberRegister::initiate(int from) {
     for (int i = from; i < this->capacity; i++) { // i = from, not i = 0
        this->timber[i] = nullptr;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, like the comments point out:

```
std::vector
```

might be a better solution.

Secondly, I suggest indenting uniformly your code to make it easier to read.

Lastly, (and if your tables are always ending up with nothing but null pointers) I think this is the problem:

```
 void TimberRegister::initiate(int from) {
 for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; i++) {
    this->timber[i] = nullptr;
```

Shouldn't `i` start from `from`? i.e. `int i = from`